# In react how can I access the id of an element inside the same element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the style of the link according to the state, until now i just wrote the query myself (i.e: this.state.active == 'today'). is there a way to use the id of the element instead?

```
<div className={styles.option}>
  <a
    id={'today'}
    onClick={this.handleLinkClick} 
    className={this.state.active == id ? styles.active : ''}
  >
    Today
  </a>
</div>
```

this code gives me the error 'id is not defined'

Comment: No, you don't have access to the id field, as it's not yet actually been embedded into the DOM at this point. This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Will this code work for you? As you are already passing a value to the id attribute you can as well pass the same value to your conditional expression.

```
<div className={styles.option}>
      <a id={'today'}
         onClick={this.handleLinkClick} 
         className={this.state.active == 'today' ? 
              styles.active 
              :
              ''
         }>
         Today
      </a>
</div>
```

If you want to convert it into dynamic it should be something like this:

```
<div className={styles.option}>
      <a id={foo}
         onClick={this.handleLinkClick} 
         className={this.state.active == foo ? 
              styles.active 
              :
              ''
         }>
         Today
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah it's better than what i did, but not what i wanted.. i know now that it's not possible, thank you anyway! :)

Comment: but may be it is possible @AlexLipnik , try to describe in detail de behavior and results you want. You may achieve what you want with a different approach.